# Concatenating String with jQuery variable

Tags: jquery

I have code like:

```
$(".lmls").click(function(){
        var groupid = $('span#gid').attr('value');
        $("#otherpaths+groupid").toggle();
    });
```

I am trying to concatenate `#otherpaths+groupid` to give me an output like:

`#otherpaths5` for example.

How can I do this in jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: `$("#otherpaths" + groupid)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#otherpaths"+groupid).toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

Take the variable out of the string:

```
"#otherpaths"+groupid
```